# Rails - belongs_to, has_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to setup a model relationship in rails and could use your help, as it's not working :0

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :request_threads
end

class RequestThread < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user, :foreign_key => :creator_id
end
```

In terms of schemas, the request_threads table has creator_id instead of user_id, maybe that's the issue?

I want to be able to do:

```
@user.request_threads
```

But this isn't working, errors. Ideas?

**UPDATED**

Error Message: "Started POST "/request_threads" for 127.0.0.1 at Wed Nov 10 22:21:41 -0800 2010
  Processing by RequestThreadsController#create as JS
  Parameters: {"request_thread"=>{"request_type_id"=>"1", "message"=>"blahdiado"}, "authenticity_token"=>"o9ibF/m8Vw4Uce5u1n3R+atD2/XVqnZcBVOdXimAZEA=", "utf8"=>"✓", "recipients"=>["4", "3"]}
  User Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE ("users"."id" = 2) LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE ("users"."id" = 2) LIMIT 1
Completed   in 63ms

NoMethodError (undefined method `user_id=' for #<RequestThread:0x1058df0d0>):
  app/controllers/request_threads_controller.rb:50:in`create'
  app/middleware/flash_session_cookie_middleware.rb:14:in `call'
"

Comment: "this isn't working" -- is there an error message?

Comment: @rwilliams, what schema do you want to see, it's huge

Comment: You don't need to. I didn't completely read the question I just got confused when I saw creator_id

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this out.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :request_threads, :foreign_key => :creator_id
end

class RequestThread < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Controller looks ok. Ok try this out in your RequestThread model.

```
alias_attribute :user_id, :creator_id
```

Comment: Thanks. tried that, same error "NoMethodError (undefined method `user_id=' for #<RequestThread:0x105875400>):"  Does my controller look right to you? "  def create
    @user = User.find(current_user)
    @request_thread = @user.request_threads.new(params[:request_thread])
"

Comment: This only works for user.request_threads not request_thread.user

Comment: Also using the :class_name argument is pointless in this case.

Comment: Yes rwilliams agreed with both your comments. First of all, the ideal solution is to rename the column in request_threads table. Yeah he can use the alias_attribute in the User model as well in case he needs request_thread.user.

Answer (score 2):

This should work for you.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :request_threads, :foreign_key => :creator_id
end

class RequestThread < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user, :foreign_key => :creator_id
end
```